# Displaying a list of Products sorted by Category and SubCategory in a DRY fashion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dry, categories, conventions

I have the following entity:

```
public class Product{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string SubCategory { get; set; }
}
```

I would ultimately like to display a page that takes an `IEnumerable<Product>` and sorts the `Products` first by `Category` - then sorts each `Category` of `Products` by `SubCategory`.

What should my ViewModel look like?

At first I came up with something like this:

```
public class ProductListViewModel{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Categories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

but then my Controller becomes full of logic to extract the unique `Categories` and `SubCategories` and I have no clean way of dealing with the fact that each `Category` has different lists of `SubCategories`.

Anyone with experience in sorting objects by category - can you nudge me in the right direction of how to approach this situation cleanly?  I can get the job done, but I feel I am making my code needlessly sloppy and not DRY.

I am also wondering if my `Product` class structured in an inappropriate way to handle `Categories`/`SubCategories` - does anyone else feel the same? (I am thinking my Categories may be better suited as separate objects entirely)

Comment: How do you want the information to be displayed on the view?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov The user will see a list of `Categories` - they will click a `Category` and a list of all the products within that `Category` will slide out.  The list of `Products` that are now visible will be sorted by `SubCategory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your question regarding the model structure, I think that Category should definitely 
be a separate entity - your database will be under normalized (the Category should not be repeated multiple times in the database). Perhaps :

```
public class Product{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
}


public class SubCategory{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This way you can separate out the Category from the Product (you could also have several Categories for a single product by having an ICollection in the Product entity). This also creates a relationship between Category and SubCategory.

Comment: Looks very reasonable.  I am unable to really focus on the response at the moment, I will return and comment when I have the time to pay the necessary attention.

Comment: This is a very good method for approaching my situation.  Thank you very much.